# Form validation using Jquery while editing

Tags: jquery-ui

I have to take agent details there are three views Add, Edit and View-All.

The Add form works as expected

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){

     var ruleSet1 = {
       required: true,
       number: true
     };

     $("#question").validate({
       rules: {
         agent_cheque_no: ruleSet1,
         pincode :ruleSet1,
       }
     });
   });
 </script>  

 <div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label"> pincode *</label>
   <div class="controls">
     <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="pincode" placeholder="pincode" required name="pincode">
   </div>
 </div>
```

The code is not functioning correctly in the Edit view (as follows):

```
 <div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label"> Pincode *</label>
   <div class="controls">
     <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="pincode" value="<?php echo $row->agent_pincode; ?>" placeholder="State" required name="pincode">
   </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: at first pincode :ruleSet1, remove comma from given string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure your both form ID is same because for edit form your form id may be different and validation code isnt write.

```
<form id="same_as_add">
     <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label"> Pincode *</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="pincode" placeholder="State" required name="pincode">
          </div>
        </div>
<form>
```

When you edit it make sure  for below form declaration

```
<form id="same_as_add">
     <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label"> Pincode *</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="pincode" value="<?php echo $row->agent_pincode; ?>" placeholder="State" required name="pincode">
          </div>
        </div>
<form>
```